# up_direction parameter in godot engine

Tags: godot

I was learning godotengine and I got confused from using up_direction parameter in move_and_slide() method. Actually, I didn't understand what does it do and what is the relation between it and is_on_floor() method.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `up_direction` parameter of `move_and_slide` tells the `KinematicBody` or `KinematicBody2D` what direction is up for identifying floor, walls, and ceiling.

As a result of calling, `move_and_slide`, the object will move, it will collide, and it will classify what it collided with according the angle with the `up_direction`. Like this:

- If the collision is roughly in the opposite direction as `up_direction`, it is a floor.
- If the collision is roughly in the same direction as `up_direction`, it is a ceiling.
- Otherwise, it is a wall.

Then `move_and_slide` will update `is_on_floor`, `is_on_wall` and `is_on_ceiling` accordingly.

And I say "roughly", because a collision in a direction that diverges less than the value of the `floor_max_angle` parameter, it will still count.

Furthermore, the `floor_max_angle` criteria is also used to decide if it will stop or slide the surface it collided with. If it will slide, that changes the velocity vector. Which is why `move_and_slide` returns a new velocity vector.

It is also worth noting that if you pass ZERO, everything is considered a wall. For example, if you pass `Vector2.ZERO` as `up_direction` to `KinematicBody2D.move_and_slide`, then it will consider everything it collides with to be a wall. Which is useful for top down games

Comment: I got the point and thank you for your help.